# Picmonkey API example edit and save image in place of original image

Tags: asp.net, image, api, image-editing

I am using Picmonkey API for editing image, its working fine means I am able to upload specific image from my server, edit it and save. But I am not getting modified image in place of original image.

I am using following code:

```html
<form method="post" action="http://www.picmonkey.com/service/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type="hidden" name="_apikey" value="e90a6073b5c3398d1c50daa08314be0a"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_import" value="example.com/img/ProfileImage.jpg"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="_close_target" value="example.com/testpic.aspx" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_export" value="example.com/Login.aspx" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_export_agent" value="server" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_export_method " value="POST" />    
        <input type="hidden" name="_export_field" value="photo" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_replace" value="confirm" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="_imageid" value="ProfileImage" />
        <input type="submit" value="Create A Custom Image"/>
    </form>
```

Actually my main purpose is on my site user registration form I need to upload image using file upload and save it on server, now if user want to edit image he will click on edit button and redirect on picmonkey site via Picmonkey API configuration and than edit image over there, when he will save the image I want new edited image must be replace with original image on server and then redirect on my site specific page.